# How can I remove the labels in a bibliography list with biblatex?

Tags: latex, biblatex

In bibtex it is very easy to remove all labels in the bibliography; as, for instance, described here
https://stackoverflow.com/a/3003759/6936361.

I cannot find the equivalent to

```
\makeatletter
\def\@biblabel#1{}
\makeatother
```

for biblatex.

If I have, for example, this code:

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage[style=alphabetic]{biblatex}

\addbibresource{foo.bib}
\begin{document}

\nocite{*}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

I get this
[image]

Instead, I would like to have something like this:
[image]
How can I remove the labels in the bibliography list without changing the style with biblatex?

Comment: Please make a compilable [mre] that will show us which documentclass and bib style you use.

Comment: I added an example. Thanks, for the remark. I do not want to change the style, I just want to define the label as empty, as it was possible without biblatex. And I don't want to change the bib file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As a quick hack, you can redefine the bibliography environment:

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage[style=alphabetic]{biblatex}

\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\defbibenvironment{bibliography}
  {\list
     {}
     {%
      \setlength{\labelwidth}{0pt}%
      \setlength{\leftmargin}{0pt}%
      \setlength{\labelsep}{0pt}%
      \addtolength{\leftmargin}{0pt}%
      \setlength{\itemsep}{\bibitemsep}%
      \setlength{\parsep}{\bibparsep}}%
      \renewcommand*{\makelabel}[1]{##1\hss}}
  {\endlist}
  {\item}


\begin{document}
\cite{knuth:ct:a}
\nocite{*}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image]

(personally I would use an `authoryear` style instead to avoid having labels in text without any correspondence in the bibliography)

Comment: How can I access each bibliographic items in References? Say, I want to put each of the items within `enumerate`?

Comment: @hola If you have a new question, please use the "ask question" button